# Auto redirect if user is logged in

Tags: php, http

I've two pages: `index.php` and `register.php`.
If the user is `guest`, he can click on `register.php`-->go to that page-->register a form and login. Upon logging in, he is redirected to index.php. Now if he/she tries to access `signup.php`-->they are automatically redirected to `index.php`. 
I'm using:

```
<?php 
   if(!isset($_SESSION['id']))
   {
      //show the form
      ....
   }
   else
   {
      header("Location: index.php");
      exit;
   }
   ?>
```

How ever, I'm getting a `Cannot modify header information` error.
How else can I make the code to redirect when `index.php` and `register.php` are two separate pages.

Comment: Make sure your redirect is the first thing you do. Are you outputting anything before redirecting the user?

Comment: @JSantos:It contain HTML elements.

Comment: You must remove them. No output before redirect

Comment: @JSantos: Thanks. I found the bug. Simple `if-else` implementation did it.!!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is create a seperate file named check_logged.php which I include at the top of pages you wish to block. What it does is check whether 
Add this to the top of your page

```
session_start();
include('php/check_logged.php');
```

Check_logged.php contains this:

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['id'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}
```

Personally I needed a second check because my forms output a confirmation message after you successfully restore your password with this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['good_message'])){ //check if a confirmation message is set, if no continue to check if the user is logged in.
    if (!empty($_SESSION['id'])) {
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit;
    }
}
```

This way if you return to the login page and want to display a confirmation message it doesn't instantly redirect you. I tend to show my messages like this:

```
<span class="error"> <?php 
    if( IsSet( $_SESSION[ "message_sent" ] ) )  {
            echo "<p align='center' style='color: #8BA870;';> " . $_SESSION[ "message_sent" ] . "</p>";
            unset( $_SESSION[ "message_sent" ] );
}?></span>
```

It is shown once after which it unsets itself. So if you refresh the page the value is nog longer 'set' and you will be redirected to home.